# css box shadow not working

Tags: html, css

The box-shadow is not working. Other div box-shadow work just fine, this is my html code:

```css
#header {
  background-color: #6666ff;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px #888888;
}

#header .headercontent .setting {
  float: right;
}

#header .headercontent a {
  color: #000066;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header .headercontent {
  list-style: none;
}
#container{  
    width:100%;  
    background-color:#ccffff;  
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="headercontent">
    <a href="index.php">
      <font size="6">Mine</font>
    </a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Cari">
    <nav class='setting'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="testingone.php">testing 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="testingtwo.php">testing 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">testing my body container</div>
```

-EDIT-
i create dummy page seems the container background color ovveride the shadow

Comment: what about it isn't working?

Comment: The code you provided does produce a box-shadow. Sometimes it will appear that the shadow isn't being applied when it's being covered by another element (that's postioned and has a high z-index)

Comment: i put the box-shadow in very parent div but the shadow is not showing up, i put the border the border show up fine i put in div header and class headercontent the shadow is in the middle div. how is it my code fault?

Comment: @zgood i've put z-index:-2 or 0 but still the shadow not showing up

Comment: Post your parent divs & css then, the parent div might be overriding the shadow

Comment: id header is my parent div next to body, i post all the css

Comment: -edit- the background color container override my shadow

Answer (score 2):

can you please be more clear on what is not working. I have tried running the same code and found the box shadow displayed.
[image]

you may also check the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/zxytmgjL/
`#header {
  background-color: #6666ff;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px #888888;
}`

Comment: hi, i've edit my post, the container div next from header background color override my shadow

Answer (score 1):

you must make header relative & make the box-shadow transparent ,

check the snippet

```css
#header {
  background-color: #6666ff;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 position: relative;
}

#header .headercontent .setting {
  float: right;
}

#header .headercontent a {
  color: #000066;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#header .headercontent {
  list-style: none;
}
#container{  
    width:100%;  
    background-color:#ccffff;  
height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="headercontent">
    <a href="index.php">
      <font size="6">Mine</font>
    </a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Cari">
    <nav class='setting'>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="testingone.php">testing 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="testingtwo.php">testing 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="container">testing my body container</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain why the header should be relative?